# All GraphQL SDL schema fields shown as depreciated in GraphQL-Voyager regardless if they actually are

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

I'm trying to check my GraphQL Schema created in **SDL** using "*[GraphQL-Voyager](https://graphql-kit.com/graphql-voyager)*", but it always shows all fields are "***DEPRECATED***" even when none of them are declared as deprecated. For an example, the following simple schema would encounter the issue:

```
schema {
  query: Query
}

type Query {
  get_CONTACTS( id: ID! ): CONTACTS
}

type CONTACTS {
  CONTACT_ID: ID!
  FIRST_NAME: String
  LAST_NAME: String
}
```

[Screen shots showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIsq7.png)

I'm new to GraphQL and currently just following what I've learned from an online course I purchased earlier, not sure what else I can try.

Any information will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!