# Voyager showing non deprecated fields as deprecated

Tags: graphql

https://github.com/graphql-kit/graphql-voyager/discussions/368

https://github.com/graphql/graphiql/discussions/3423

Hi all,
I am not sure if this is the right place or audience to post this. I tried the github voyager repo discussion, but I did not get any feedback there.
Our team members noticed that lately when we run a query on voyager we are seeing deprecate fields for fields that are not deprecated in our code. This is happening for all our APIs. Was there any recent changes that could cause voyager to show deprecated fields for fields that are actually not deprecated?

I found this on stackoverflow but no answer.
[All GraphQL SDL schema fields shown as depreciated in GraphQL-Voyager regardless if they actually are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77083814/all-graphql-sdl-schema-fields-shown-as-depreciated-in-graphql-voyager-regardless)

Thank you,

None of those fields are deprecated in our code source:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQacc.png)

I tried to query different APIs and was expecting no deprecated field warning, but I still saw it, even though those fields are not deprecated fields.